# Plutext's PDF Converter restrictions

Tags: java, docx4j

I have planned to use up `docx4j` library for my JAVA application for `docx` to `PDF` conversion.

But, since the version `v3.3.0` of `DOCX4j` the PDF output is by default via `Plutext's` commercial PDF Converter, will i be restricted to the number of documents i can have converted? or will there be any other similar limitations?

Comment: Maybe you should ask the developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.docx4java.org/forums/pdf-output-f27/higher-fidelity-pdf-output-now-available-t2117.html

> In docx4j 3.3.0 and later, this is the default way of creating a PDF.
>   The default configuration is to use
>   https://converter-eval.plutext.com:443 for conversion. See the link
>   below for how to change that to your local install.
>
> A side benefit is that this new approach is much faster than the FO
>   approach.
>
> We're offering this as a commercial component, so we can continue to
>   invest in it. The existing FO approach will of course remain free and
>   open source. (To use that instead, just add the export-FO jar and its
>   dependencies to your classpath. See further
>   https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-export-fo )

You can install your own copy (and really should please if you want to use it; the default instance is solely so you can easily check the fidelity and we are likely to rate limit the eval instance in the near future).

To use your own instance, see https://converter-eval.plutext.com/client_java.html which says:

> To use your own instance, tell docx4j where it is.
>
> You can do that via docx4j property "com.plutext.converter.URL".
>
> You should set that in docx4j.properties; a sample properties file can
>   be found on GitHub
>
> Add docx4j.properties to your classpath, if you didn't have it
>   already.
>
> Or alternatively, you could set the property programmatically:
>
> Docx4jProperties.setProperty(
>       "com.plutext.converter.URL", 
>       "https://converter-eval.plutext.com:443/v1/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/convert");

Your instance will show an eval watermark until you apply a license key (which you'll need to pay for to get).  As per above, if you want free docx to PDF, you could try the export-FO approach.

Comment: Thank you. And I did try the export-FO approach before having used the converter. There were many formatting issues with respect to that. You have any suggestions with the formatting while using export-FO approach ?